# Converting excel to Tableau syntax

Tags: tableau-api

Can someone please convert the following in Tableau Syntax for me please - We have tried for hours!

=IF(Table1[@[Order Value]]<0,0,IF(Table1[@[D Complete Act]]TODAY()-180,0,IF(AND(Table1[@[File Wise Doc ID]]>0,Table1[@[D Complete Act]]TODAY()-120),0,IF(ISBLANK(Table1[@[File Wise Doc ID]]),Table1[@[Order Value]],Table1[@Fwnet]))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to logically break your function up and apply the same logic to a Tableau Calculated field below.

I'm not familiar with some of the Excel syntax - namely the way you're applying TODAY() right next to a field without an operator. I presume this means a [D Complete Act] less than than a certain number of days old.

It may need a little tweaking, but hopefully this at least gets you the idea of how to translate from Excel to Tableau:

```
IF(Table1[@[Order Value]]<0,
    0,
    IF(Table1[@[D Complete Act]]TODAY()-180,
        0,
        IF(AND(Table1[@[File Wise Doc ID]]>0, 
        Table1[@[D Complete Act]]TODAY()-120),
                0,
                IF(ISBLANK(Table1[@[File Wise Doc ID]]),
                    Table1[@[Order Value]],
                    Table1[@Fwnet]))))
```

~

```
IF [Order Value] < 0 
    Then 0 
Else
    If [D Complete Act] < DATEADD('day', -180, TODAY()) 
       Then 0 
       Else
           If [File Wise Doc ID] > 0 
           AND [D Complete Act] < DATEADD('day', -120, TODAY()) 
               Then 0
               Else 
                   If ISNULL([File Wise Doc ID])
                       Then [Order Value]
                       Else [Fwnet]
                   END
           END
    END
END
```

Comment: I'm getting an error "Can not mix aggregate and non-aggregate..."

Comment: Are any of the Tableau fields listed above Table Calculations?

Comment: All resolved - need to turn non-aggregate data to aggregate - we used ATTR () to do so. Thank you VERY MUCH!

Comment: Excellent! Please mark it as the correct answer (click the check mark) and upvote so that it may be referenced by others in the future. Thank you!